# How can a trader bot possibly not have a basic security mechanism?

Tags: trading, online-trading, automation

I recently heard about some broken trader bot in 2010 or something which suddenly started buying or selling stocks at ridiculous prices, to the point of emptying a massive bank account, fundamentally affecting the stock market.

How is this possible? The very first thing I would code in before going live would be something like this in the top of the script:

```
if ($amount_spent_today > 5000)
    die();
```

How did somebody with so much money and access to auto-trade not build in such a basic, obvious security mechanism? It sounds extremely strange to me. Downright *impossible*. I frankly don't believe it.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but this question seems to boil down to "how could someone write software with a bug in it?". If that's so, then the question is probably not a great fit for this stack.

Comment: Because humans are not infallible. Or perhaps the situation that caused the wild trades was not accounted for. Or perhaps the story is untrue.

Comment: @Upper_Case That's not at all what I'm asking. I'm asking how it's possible for it to not have this basic mechanism implemented. This is not possible to get wrong.

Comment: (What's with the constant downvotes when asking questions here? It's so tiresome.)

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20 - of course you would prevent the specific bug that happened from happening. But what _other_ bugs could possibly be there that you _don't_ see ahead of time.

Comment: @Rehmel Um... it's absolutely possible for a basic element of a system to be coded improperly, but that's not a personal finance question. The appearance of this question not being related to finance at all is probably what is attracting downvotes.

Comment: It's not a good question for this forum. This forum is designed for answerable questions regarding personal finance, not speculation on an event that happened 10 years ago (and perhaps is factually questionable).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about personal finance.

Comment: @rehmel - if it helps,. No one is downvoting you personally. They (including me) think this just isn't a good fit for the scope of this site. This is how we curate content here. The site is about personal finance, and how a bug got into software isn't really on topic, even if it just happens to be software that is related to finance.

Answer (score 2):

Last year, some [Robinhood users discovered a glitch](https://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/robinhood-investing-infinite-money-leverage-glitch-shows-risk-investing-game-2019-11-1028685860)  which enabled them to trade with infinite leverage.  The cheat code enabled investors to sell covered call options, adding  the value of the options to the user’s original cash on hand, allowing them to borrow larger and larger amounts, with no limit.  It was reported that one Robinhood member achieved 500x leverage, buying more than $1.7 million worth of Advanced Micro Devices AMD,  by  selling $1.6 million in calls. Another user turned $2k into $50k and lost it.

I am not familiar with your 2010 trader bot incident.  However, you asked, "How is this possible?"  Bad programming leads to bad results (in this case regarding proper margin calculations) and errors like this have been commonplace with Robinhood.  It's a Mickey Mouse operation.